# Encrypt and Decrypt in bcryptjs

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I want to encrypt an email id and decrypt that how? I checked the documentation, but it only shows password encryption, and that is showing a true or false result.

Any way to encrypt and decrypt email id, please help me?

Comment: bcrypt doesn't encrypt, Its a hashing Algorithm, use `crypto` package, comes with nodejs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [cryptr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptr) for encryption and decryption. With bcrypt you can't perform encryption and decryption of data.
cryptr can be used as follows:

```
const Cryptr = require('cryptr');
const cryptr = new Cryptr('myTotalySecretKey');
let email = some@mail.com;
let encryptdEmail = cryptr.encrypt(email);
console.log("Decrypted email = ", cryptr.decrypt(encryptdEmail ));
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried to use the suggested library but it causes issues. I will strongly suggest [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
let email = some@mail.com;
let encryptdEmail = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(email, 'secret key 1').toString();
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptdEmail, 'secret key 1');
var decryptdEmail = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log("Decrypted email = ", decryptdEmail);
```